# Using jQuery to check text input and make second text required

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to have jQuery force my `time` field to be visible and required if the `phone` field contains any text. Basically once the user starts to fill the `Phone` field, I'd like the next field `(Time)` to appear.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" target="files/contact.php">
  <label for="full_name">Your Name: </label><input type="text" name="full_name" required="required" /><br />
  <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /><br />
  <div id="time">
    <label for="time">Best time to call: </label><input type="text" name="time" /><br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn" />
</form>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#time").hide();
});

var inp = $("#phone").val();
if ($.trim(inp).length > 0) {
  $("#time").show();
  $("#time").addClass('required');
}
```

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/flipnotic/pen/QNdqxj)

Comment: Please do not tag your question with [tag:jquery-validate] when the question contains nothing about this plugin.  Edited.  Otherwise, edit the question to contain a [MVCE... emphasis on the "C" for "complete"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The Codepen is great but not a substitute for including the actual code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGgrOB

Use `.on(keyup, myFunction)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#time").hide();
});

$('#phone').on("keyup", function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    $("#time").show();
    $("#time").find("[name=time]").attr('required', 'required');
  } else {
    $("#time").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked our the demo, and it works well. Though, when I try to submit the form while leaving `#time` blank, it still submits. I'm assuming my `$("#time").addClass('required');` Isn't working?

Comment: @flipnotic - I updated the answer accordingly.. check it out now.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGgrOB

Comment: great.. glad to help